# How to disable button in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
  $scope.date = moment(currentDate);

  $scope.date1 = moment(currentDate).add(-1, 'days');

  function checkDate(){
   if ($scope.date > $scope.date1) {
    return true;
        }
      else{
       return false;
         }
 };

  checkDate(); 




  <button ng-disabled="checkDate()" ng-click="myFunc()" style="margin-left:190px; font-size:8.5px;     background-color: antiquewhite;
        border-color: white;"><strong>9:00Am-1:00PM</strong> <br><b>5:00PM-8:00PM</b></button>



    $scope.myFunc = function() {
    $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe;
    $scope.showtime($scope.timeslot);
  }
```

i want to disable the button but not hide.
now i don't understand what is wrong in code button is not showing in disabled mode and the myFunc() is working now , 
when the button in disabled mode then no function or say nothing click on button

Comment: try adding $scope.checkDate = checkDate

Comment: checkDate() returns a Boolean value. You're not currently using it anywhere sensibly. Also, you can change your checkDate function to simply `return $scope.date > $scope.date1;`. Don't ever return true or false based on a Boolean condition that is already true or false by definition.

Comment: nothing is happened .

Answer (score 2):

```
checkDate()
```

must be associated with `scope` in order to work.

```
<button ng-disabled="checkDate()" ng-click="myFunc()" style="margin-left:190px; font-size:8.5px;     background-color: antiquewhite;
        border-color: white;"><strong>9:00Am-1:00PM</strong> <br><b>5:00PM-8:00PM</b></button>
```

And in controller you define `checkDate`

```
$scope.checkDate = function(){
   if ($scope.date > $scope.date1) {
         return true;
   }
   else{
         return false;
   }
 };
```

Also make sure `moment(currentDate)` and `moment(currentDate).add(-1, 'days')` must return javascript date object in order to make the comparison happen.

Comment: nothing is happened i used $scope.checkDate in ng-disabled

Comment: there must be some console error either in your code or moment is not returning the date object.

Comment: i checked but no error is seen , i checked the code with console.log() and i find the exact value but nothing happened on button.

Comment: you are right it provide me json data but how can i resolve this problem , i have no idea

Answer (score 0):

Updating the answer based on the comment.

if you have 3 button like below with dates associated with those.

```
 <button ng-disabled="checkDate('2016-06-25')" ng-click="myFunc()" style="margin-left:190px; font-size:8.5px;     background-color: antiquewhite;
    border-color: white;"><strong>25/06/2016</strong> <br><b>5:00PM-8:00PM</b></button>

    <button ng-disabled="checkDate('2016-06-26')" ng-click="myFunc()" style="margin-left:190px; font-size:8.5px;     background-color: antiquewhite;
    border-color: white;"><strong>26/06/2016</strong> <br><b>5:00PM-8:00PM</b></button>

    <button ng-disabled="checkDate('2016-06-30')" ng-click="myFunc()" style="margin-left:190px; font-size:8.5px;     background-color: antiquewhite;
    border-color: white;"><strong>30/06/2016</strong> <br><b>5:00PM-8:00PM</b></button>
```

you need to declare the function like this in the controller.

```
var currentDate = new Date();

$scope.date1 = moment(currentDate).add(-1, 'days');

$scope.checkDate = function(buttonDate){


$scope.date = moment(new Date(buttonDate));  


if ($scope.date < $scope.date1) {

   return true;
}
else
{
   return false;
}
}
```

Check the working plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/J85Rx0YjhNKj0gYqjhhF?p=preview

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i try but nothing effective for me

Comment: check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/gqnLdy7JJYvatMxJn4Q8?p=preview if it helps or if you can provide a plunker/fiddle of your issue.

Comment: sir, it shows all button disabled as i added few more buttons, it cannot take the conditions as i described or i wanted that match current date with previous date and disabled buttons which is in previous date

Comment: Could you update this plunker and create the issue. the plunker is right now setting the current date default as the current date but i think you wanted the date to be compared against the date values in the button.

Comment: I have updated the answer , hope this will help you. I assumed few logic like passing the button date to compare.

Comment: its ok but i find better result